# IE10 opacity not bug with older versions of jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-10

I wrote a little lightbox video player script a while back which we use on 3 of our web sites.  One of our websites is hosted by a third party that injects an old version (1.4.3) of jquery and we can't control that.  Up until IE10 the lightbox/video player script ran fine in all browsers but it's not working in IE10 when this older version of jquery is used.  Later versions of jquery in IE10 work fine.  I think the issue it's having is with the lines below.  Does anyone know if there was a change in the way that IE10 handles opacity and how I can update the script below to support IE10?

```
props.overlay.css({ top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%", height: methods.getMaxHeight() + "px", opacity: .25 });
props.dv.css({ opacity: 1 });
```

Edit: I was reading that you could namespace jquery in order to load another version of it.  I tried doing that following the example on the jquery web site but couldn't get it to work.  In my page I had the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq183 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  jq183(document).ready(function(){
    jq183(".videoplayer").VideoPlayer();
});
</script>
```

The error I received was "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'VideoPlayer' "  I'm guessing I need to change my videoplayer.js file but I'm not sure what needs changed.  Has anyone ever done this before and have any pointers?

Comment: My guess would be IE10 properly handles opacity like other browsers, but jQuery 1.4.3 doesn't know anything about IE10.

Comment: That's what I wondered.  But, I wouldn't think that v1.8.3 that is working with IE10 would know anything about IE10 either?

Comment: IE10 definitely existed in some shape or form (probably a platform preview) before 1.8.3

Comment: What is the exact issue you're experiencing?

Comment: The div's opacity isn't changing from 0 to 100.

Comment: @geoffswartz Load the `jQuery.fn.VideoPlayer` plugin after jQuery.1.8.3.js. That will fix the error.